# Typescript: how to make addiction from one field to another?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, I have interface for `select`. I need have type for `value`. If `multiple` is equal `true`, `value` type must be `string[]` or `string` if `multiple` disabled.

```
interface SelectProps {
  multiple?: boolean;
  value: string | string[];
}
```

Component:

```
const Select = (props: SelectProps) => {
   // code
};
```

I tried to use generic, like this

```
interface SelectProps<Multiple extends boolean | undefined> {
  multiple?: boolean;
  value: Multiple extends true ? string[] : string;
}


const Select = (props: SelectProps<typeof props.multiple>) => {
   // code
};
```

but I recieve error: `'multiple' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.`

Comment: A generic seems like the wrong tool here. You probably want [a discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: @VLAZ in start i tried repeat this solution [material-ui/Autocomplete](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v4.x/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.d.ts#L220-L225)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` should also be a generic and it should forward type parameter to `SelectProps`
Also, `multiple` should be of type `Multiple`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQDYQWAClAewAcBnAHgFkBXDMYIrZCAD0hABMTkAjAgrOCGQAfZFQ4QYoCOwB8yAN4AoZKuQBbGnQYQA-AC5k1WvSwBuFWoBucDFQiHj2xizadkYKPeS7kJT6AA5gDaALrIhv5QQRYAvkoJMOI4wARC6Fg4lFqmKK4QHFy8-BCCImISUiAysgAURISkhhnYeI3kTrmyAJSKlqpKsWZAA)